# $.when().done() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to load html on to a page via jquery ajax. Then, after the html has loaded, I want to parse it for certain data that will be in the loaded html, and use it to create map markers. So I need the load method to act synchronously, so that the html is definitely loaded before my setMarkers() method tries to parse it.

```
$.when($("#orders").load("datadisp.aspx")).done(function () {
    setMarkers();
});
```

I thought the current set up that I have is supposed to do exactly that, but I can tell from the debugger that setMarkers() is still being called before the load has completed, because when I put a breakpoint on setMarkers() and inspect the html after it has hit this breakpoint, I can see that the expected html has not loaded yet. Can somebody show me the right way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: may be you are getting an error from server... try putting a fail callback and chek it

Answer (score 6):

The issue you have is that `load()` does not return a promise that can be used with `$.when`. If you want to execute some code after the `load()` has completed, put it in the callback handler:

```
$("#orders").load("datadisp.aspx", function() {
    setMarkers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), because that method is part of the [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, which implements the **Promise interface**, and the [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object returned by [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) implement the **Promise interface**, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a **[Promise](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise)** (see [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information)

A better approach could be as follow:

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "datadisp.aspx"
    //dataType: "html"
  })
).then(
  function done(data) {
    console.info("done!");
    console.log(data);
    setMarkers();
  },
  function fail(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
  }
);
```

You can just use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and transport/handle the [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848934/2247494*

Or you can use the [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object with [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to handle the [Promise](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) interface:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923089/2247494*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load WebForm or Html page then use load and pass function in handler of load and do rest stuff.

```
$("#orders").load("datadisp.aspx", setMarkers);

/*Handler function*/
function setMarkers(data)
{
/*Code*/
}
```